# Can I load javascript code using <link> tag?

Tags: html, css, javascript

Can I load javascript code using `<link>` tag in my website ?

For example I have a javascript file, `test.js`, which contains the simple code `alert('hello');`

Can I make the popup window appear using:

```
<link href="test.js"></link>
```

Comment: `link` tag is normally used for including CSS. Do you mean the `a` tag (anchor)?

Comment: Yes, you can prefetch/preload javascript, css and other assets with `<link>` tag. But browser doesn't execute the script, it only schedules it to be downloaded and cached for later usage.

Answer (score 56):

No. There was a proposal to allow:

```
<link rel="script" href=".../script.js"/>
```

analogously to stylesheets. This is even quoted as an example in the [HTML 4 DTD](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/dtd.html), but browser implementation never happened. Shame, as this would have been much cleaner.

Comment: Even browser makers don't follow

Comment: Yeah it would be much cleaner, but then it would be easy for miners to add coinhive as a favicon.ico file (as it already happened, but I guess it happened using a script tag, not a link one).

Answer (score 21):

You need to use the `<script>` tag to include JavaScript source files:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="mysrc.js"></script>
```

The end tag must be the full `</script>`, don't abbreviate the way you can with some tags as in `<script type="text/javascript" src="..."/>`.

Yes, alert statements in the included source will appear when they are evaluated by the browser.

For information on the uses of the `<link>` tag, see [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.3).

Comment: Just one question, this script tag which has link to the java script, should it be in the head tag or in the body tag. Because if I put it in the body tag it's not working

Answer (score 15):

Modern browsers support the `preload` keyword, which is used to preload various resources, including scripts. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Preloading_content):

> The `preload` value of the `<link>` element's `rel` attribute allows you to
>   write declarative fetch requests in your HTML `<head>`, specifying
>   resources that your pages will need very soon after loading, which you
>   therefore want to start preloading early in the lifecycle of a page
>   load, before the browser's main rendering machinery kicks in. This
>   ensures that they are made available earlier and are less likely to
>   block the page's first render, leading to performance improvements.
>
> A simple example might look like this (see our [JS and CSS example
>   source](https://github.com/mdn/html-examples/tree/master/link-rel-preload/js-and-css), and also [live](https://mdn.github.io/html-examples/link-rel-preload/js-and-css/)):
>
> ```
> <head>
>   <meta charset="utf-8">
>   <title>JS and CSS preload example</title>
>
>   <link rel="preload" href="style.css" as="style">
>   <link rel="preload" href="main.js" as="script">
>
>   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
> </head>
>
> <body>
>   <h1>bouncing balls</h1>
>   <canvas></canvas>
>
>   <script src="main.js"></script>
> </body>
> ```

Answer (score 6):

**Possible rationale why not**

- `link` elements are only allowed where "Metadata content" is allowed, typically `head`, and not in the `body`. See: [Contexts in which this element can be used](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-link-element). All embedded elements that go in the `body` have separate elements for them: `img`, `iframe`, etc.
- `link` elements must be empty, and `script` may be non-empty. See: [Content model](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-link-element)

Therefore it is natural to have a separate element for JavaScript, and since we must have a separate element, it is better not to duplicate functionality with `link rel="script"`.

This theory also explains why `img` and `style` have separate elements:

- `img` can be placed in the body, so it gets a separate element, even though it must be empty.
- `style` can be non-empty, so it gets a separate element, even though until HTML5 it could not be placed in the `body` (now it can via `scoped`, but still not to include external scripts).

Apparently Tim Berners-Lee wanted everything to be done with `<a`: https://youtu.be/3QEoJRjxnxQ?t=901 !

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript code would generally be loaded using a script tag, like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question directly, no. Not by that method. However I was led to this question while searching a similar issue which lead me to this question. Seeing the answers already supplied which for the most part are correct I went to check syntax on http://w3schools.com/ . It seems that with HTML5 there is a new attribute for for the script elements in html.

This new attribute allows javascript files to be defered or loaded and executed asynchronously (not to be confused with AJAX).

I'm just going to leave the link here and let you read up on the details yourself as it is already supplied on the internet.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_async.asp

Comment: Be careful when adding links to w3schools: you risk getting downvoted on SO just because of that =)

Comment: I don't see how the `async` attribute is related to the original question at all. As I understand, the question is more about the syntax for referencing a JS file from HTML.

Answer (score 1):

The other option for this is, you can dynamically insert a script file into the current document, by creating a SCRIPT tag, setting its "src" attribute to the URI of the script, and then inserting it as a child of the page's HEAD node.

Doing those things will get the browser to fetch the script file, load it into the document, and execute it.

Answer (score 1):

<del>Typically you would use a `<script>` tag, but actually, you can do `<link href="test.js"></link>` as you described. [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/load-script-with-link-8cto4v) is a example</del>

I'm wrong here. Apparently, Parcel is doing some special stuff and the final output uses a `<script>` tag. You need a script tag (even if you use `<link>` to preload a `.js` file, you still are forced to use a `<script>` tag to actually load it).

Leaving this here so that others might not be confused by Parcel's bundling magic as I was.

Answer (score 0):

No. A Link tag like is for CSS files or for [relational](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/links.html) links (like `next`).

This is not the way to load javascript into the page. You need to use the `<script>` tag:

```
<script language="javascript" src="file.js" />
```