# Why do we use <script> for scripts, but not <style> for external CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, html, w3c

A relative of mine who started to learn Web Development asked me this question.

Why `<script src="min.js"></script>` and `<link rel="stylesheet" href="min.css">`? Why not `<style href="min.css"></style>`. Why do we use `link` tag to add external CSS in the page but when we link CSS to page but we use `<style>...</style>` when we write CSS inside `<head>`?

I told him that it's because of spec. Is there any more info to give to him?

Comment: You can also do this: `<style type="text/css">@import url("style.css");</style>`.

Comment: @Rocket but it's not advisable by Yslow team http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#csslink

Comment: they mentioned **In IE @import behaves the same as using <link> at the bottom of the page, so it's best not to use it.**

Comment: I just thought I'd point out another way to do that, just to make things more interesting.

Comment: @Rocket - I agree. your comment made this more interesting

Comment: **IE, it's best not to use it.** FIFY

Comment: check this ans : https://stackoverflow.com/a/61873562/6293856

Answer (score 45, accepted):

It's historical... coincidence? You can recommend him reading [part about Past of diveintohtml5.info](http://diveintohtml5.info/past.html), where there are some interesting stories, actually mail correspondences, between web developers. Web developers means they were, *in fact*, developing the Web we see nowadays ;)

I.e. `<img>` tag we are used to:

```
<IMG SRC="file://foobar.com/foo/bar/blargh.xbm">
```

could be:

```
<ICON name="NoEntry" href="http://note/foo/bar/NoEntry.xbm">
```

or

```
<A HREF="..." INCLUDE>See photo</A>
```

or

```
<INCLUDE HREF="...">
```

but [finally devs decided to stick with `<img>`, which was already implemented](http://1997.webhistory.org/www.lists/www-talk.1993q1/0257.html):

> We’re not prepared to support INCLUDE/EMBED at this point. … So we’re
>   probably going to go with  (not ICON, since not all
>   inlined images can be meaningfully called icons). For the time being,
>   inlined images won’t be explicitly content-type’d; down the road, we
>   plan to support that (along with the general adaptation of MIME).
>   Actually, the image reading routines we’re currently using figure out
>   the image format on the fly, so the filename extension won’t even be
>   significant.

I don't know direct answer to your question, but I'm pretty curious about `<link>` tag, too. Finding answer would probably include some web archives digging.

Comment: I was about to write a similar answer - it is probably just an implementation thing. One browser implemented it in one way the other did something else and eventualy one got into the specification. But I would really love to hear from someone who got his part writing the specifications back in the days.

Comment: Whatever was decided in past it's ok but W3C can change in future for example in HTML 5 `text/css` and `text/javascript` are not required.

Comment: I love this answer but this isn't the answer to the actual question in the head. Can we perhaps get more people to comment on this so we can find the actual answer?

Answer (score 27):

There is a difference, at least from the W3C's point of view.

A `<style>` element introduces a block of CSS rules that apply to the current document. However, external style sheets are actually considered as whole documents [related](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.3) to the current page, and user agents are free to ignore such documents, depending on the `type` and `media` attributes of the link. For instance:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="screen.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css" />
```

In this situation, user agents would typically only follow one of the links, either the `screen` one (for normal rendering) or the `print` one (for, well, printing). The idea was to preserve bandwidth by only downloading the appropriate resource, instead of fetching everything and filtering on the media type later.

This is mentioned in the specification:

> When the `LINK` element links an external style sheet to a document, the
>   `type` attribute specifies the style sheet language and the `media`
>   attribute specifies the intended rendering medium or media. User
>   agents may save time by retrieving from the network only those style
>   sheets that apply to the current device.

Comment: But We can also define media inside a external css file. Which is preferred these days to save http requests

Comment: @Jitendra, indeed we can, but then we'd have to download the CSS file in order to check its media type. Putting that information in the `<link>` element allows the user agent to completely disregard the resource, without having to load it first before it can decide to do so.

Comment: What about CSS 3 media queries which is for same medium but for different screen sizes. Do you prfere to use seperate css file for each media like, print, screen etc?

Comment: Well, CSS3 is still (relatively) new. For now, I indeed prefer using a different CSS file for each media type, with common styles imported using `@import` directives. (That said, I don't use multiple media types very often.)

Comment: @hamidi [implementors don't always follow the spec](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/implementor).

Comment: But style elements also support `media` attribute like, `<style type="text/css" media="screen">` We can have two style elements, one for `media="screen"` and other for `media="print"`. I don't understand why `src` attribute isn't allowed for style element.

Comment: @user31782 you can petition the W3C if you like, but people here can't do anything about it.

Answer (score 4):

They both have a basically identical meaning, and you have spotted a sort of inconsistency in HTML. The cause of this is that the standards were based on the implementations of different browsers. Different browsers came up with the attributes in the different tags, and the W3C just decided to keep some of the inconsistencies in order to maintain backwards compatability.

Elements that use `src`: `script img iframe input video frame`

Elements that use `href`: `a link base`

Comment: There is no inconsistency in HTML. `src` is used for replaced elements. Those elements are a part of the HTML document. While, `href` is used for linking to other documents. Here, we specify a 'relationship' of the external document to the current document.

Comment: @FelipeElia: Actually, I'd argue that using `<script>`'s `src` attribute is not a link but a replacement. The page will behave identically whether you use `src` or you include the script inline (which would be considered "replacement").

Comment: @rinogo yep, you have a good point there! Thinking about it now, it's true for images too. Although we generally point to other files, we can always embed them with base64, what is not true with href elements. To use an inline CSS we'd have to use <style> instead of <link>.

Comment: Anyone who has worked with more than a toy example with HTML forms would not say there is "no inconsistency in HTML". e.g. input.value vs input.checked checkbox is not POSTed, you cant disable a radio button, the list goes on and on.

Answer (score 1):

The `<link>` tag is used to "link" other documents to the current one, and describe it's relationship, or `rel`, with it.

You can also use `<link>` to link other things to the document.  For example, favicons:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
```

Comment: Agree: link can be used to link to many things (one for each rel type), so the really surprising point about the interface is why not use `link` for scripts as asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631635/can-i-load-javascript-code-using-link-tag).

Answer (score 1):

This might explain things, I guess: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html

Answer (score 1):

Possible reason for `link ref` vs `style`:

`link` can only go on the `head`, where "Metadata content" is allowed, typically `head`,

`style` could not go in the `body` before HTML5 (now you can with `scoped`, but still not to external styles). Therefore, the choice between `link ref` and `style src` is arbitrary.

`script`, however, could already include an external script in the `body` before HTML5, so there had to be `script src`. But since it had to exist, why not allow it in the `head` as well (where `script` was already allowed), and disallow `link rel=script` to avoid duplication?

Apparently Tim Berners-Lee wanted everything to be done with `<a`: https://youtu.be/3QEoJRjxnxQ?t=901 !

Comment: It's a nice answer, but <a> uses href and it was always possible to have it in the body...