# why do we have to use "link" tag for css files

Tags: html, css

Why this is not allowed:

```
<style src="someCssFile.css"></style>
```

whereas this is allowed:

```
<script src="someJsFile.js"></script>
```

I don't understand why i have to use link tag for css files. I think it would make more sense to use style tag.

Comment: As much sense as that would make, that isn't a part of HTML, so there's not much point discussing it.

Comment: @4castle I thought maybe there's a special reason that i didn't know. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't clear what your question was. I don't know why it isn't like that, but it's likely there isn't a canonical answer as to why unless someone who played a part in writing the spec wrote about it at some point.

Comment: ***Its not in W4C standards.***. We can't change HTML coding

Comment: It turns out this question actually has a duplicate! Read [this interesting post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7122492/5743988).

Comment: @ArunaWarnasooriya I don't want to change standards. I just wanted to know if there's a special reason for this rule.

Comment: @4castle Thanks! I was looking for this question but i couldn't find it. Probably because of it's strange title :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do we use <script> for scripts, but not <style> for external CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7122492/why-do-we-use-script-for-scripts-but-not-style-for-external-css)

Answer (score 6):

Do you know when all these tags introduced in HTML? There is a reason why the `<LINK>` tag is used instead of the `<style>` tag.

It makes the most sense for individuals using HTML who want to see where HTML has been and where it is going.

---

### HTML1.0

- HTML1.0 was the earliest version of HTML, used from 1989 to 1994. It was a very limited version and only contained 20 elements. But there was no link or style tag in the 20 elements.

---

### HTML2.0

- This version was created in 1995, with significant improvements to HTML1.0.
  A `<link>` tag was added to this version. The `<LINK>` tag is presented as a general purpose link to other documents. Styling sheets are indicated as a possibility.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
```

---

### HTML3.2

- The HTML3.2 version was endorsed by the W3 consortium in January 1997 and was approved by many, including notable browsers such as Netscape and Microsoft.
  And this version included a style and script tag. `<style>` tag "Reserved for future use with internal style sheet."

```html
<style type="text/css"> </style>
```

---

So the `<link>` tag is already used to include the external style in the page.
The `<style>` tag was introduced after the `<link>` tag, but it is not used to include external style.

Because there was already a `<link>` tag to include the external style and HTML has never devalued a single tag.
Sources used: [Link](http://www.martinrinehart.com/frontend-engineering/engineers/html/html-tag-history.html)