# Django, trouble with static files

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I'm having a lot of trouble getting all my static files to serve up. In my `settings.py`, I have:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

I'm using Django 1.6, and according to the official documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/

Since I have `debug=True`, this should suffice.

Then in my templates:

```
<link type="text/javascript" href="{% static 'jquery-1.11.1.js' %}" />
<link type="text/javascript" href="{% static 'jquery-1.11.1.min.js' %}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'bootstrap.min.css' %}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'jumbotron.css' %}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'custom.css' %}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'simple-sidebar.css' %}" />
```

All the CSS works fine. When I load my page, looking in Chrome's developer tools, they're coming from `/static`, and I have all these files stored in the same dir. But the `.js` files are not loading at all. They work fine if I link to the CDN.

Comment: Note that you're loading jQuery twice... Once minimised and once not.

Comment: Just a wild shot, would you change you href to src in js importing

Comment: @Basic Yes, I had both of those there because I can't get it to work and I'm just throwing stuff against the wall to see if it works. I've tried it with both .min.js alone and .js alone and the issue persists.

Comment: @JerryMeng Can you give me an example of what that would look like?

Comment: Make sure debug is enabled AND you are using runserver

Comment: Also make sure your files are actually at `STATIC_ROOT`

Comment: I believe @JerryMeng meant `<link type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'jquery-1.11.1.min.js' %}" />` - note `src` not `href`. I [don't think this will work](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2631785/156755). Try changing it to be `<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'jquery-1.11.1.min.js' %}"></script>`

Comment: @Basic, ah yes! I just noticed the src but forgot the tag name. I thought it is kind of weird of using link, but didn't realize it should be script.

Comment: @JerryMeng I did something similar... Assumed href would be ok if link was used but didn't think link was wrong until you made me look twice. Such is life.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is *link* in

```
<link type="text/javascript" href="{% static 'jquery-1.11.1.min.js' %}" />
```

It should be

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'jquery-1.11.1.min.js' %}"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, this fixed my Jquery, but for some reason my Bootstrap is now broken, so in my template:   `<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'jquery-1.11.1.min.js' %}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'bootstrap.min.css' %}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'jumbotron.css' %}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'custom.css' %}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'simple-sidebar.css' %}" />`

Answer (score 2):

As I said in the comments, with `<script>` tags, they [shouldn't be self-closing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work) so

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'jquery-1.11.1.min.js' %}"></script>
```

note the `<script ...></script>` instead of `<script .../>`

This is probably why your subsequent link tags aren't being processed properly

Comment: My pleasure. If our answers helped you, consider upvoting and/or accepting with the arrows and tick on the left. Welcome to SO and hope to see you around in future