# Laravel 5 : JQuery error

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-5

I'm Having a problem with a JQuery I pass the links like:

```
<link href="{{asset('plugins/archivos_admin/bjqs-1.js')}}">
<link href="{{asset('plugins/archivos_admin/organictabs.js')}}">
```

them I make the script:

```
<script>
     $(function() {
        $("#example-one").organicTabs();    
        $("#example-two").organicTabs({
                "speed": 200
            });
        });
    </script>
```

and I used in the index.blade.php:

```
              <div id="example-one" align="center">  <-- It's called here.          
                <ul class="nav">
                <!--
                  <li class="fecha-nav">
                  <span class="tit_fecha_num" align="center"> 22 </span> 
                  <span class="tit_fecha" align="center"> DE OCTUBRE DE 2015 </span>
                  </li>
                  -->
                  <li class="espacio-nav">&nbsp;</li>
                  <li class="nav-one"><a href="#manana">MAÑANA</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-two"><a href="#tarde" class="current" >TARDE</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-three"><a href="#noche">NOCHE</a></li>                                                               
                </ul>   
                <div id="prueba" align="center">      
                  <div class="list-wrap" align="center">                            
                    <ul style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: none;" id="manana" >
         </ul>                        
                    <ul id="tarde">
                    </ul>  
                    <!--- noche -->     
                    <ul style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: none;" id="noche" >
                      <!---->
                    </ul>
                  </div> <!-- END List Wrap -->    
                </div> <!-- prueba -->
              </div> <!-- END Organic Tabs (Example One) -->
```

It didn't work and it show me in the browser this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).organicTabs is not a function
```

Any idea who can i fix this problem.

Comment: Try with: `<script src="{{asset('plugins/archivos_admin/bjqs-1.js')}}"></script> `

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the system cannot find the JS file. So, try to change the calls to:

```
<script src="{{asset('/plugins/archivos_admin/bjqs-1.js')}}">
<script src="{{asset('/plugins/archivos_admin/organictabs.js')}}">
```

Check if the file is correctly found.

Comment: Thanks I didn't check the detail when i was using the code

Answer (score 0):

Script files (`.js` files) can't be loaded by the browser when called by a `<link>` tag, for this you need to use the `<script>` tag like so:

```
<script src="{{asset('plugins/archivos_admin/bjqs-1.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('plugins/archivos_admin/organictabs.js')}}"></script>
```

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2631785/3666810) on SO, it's being explained a bit more.
Using this should cause the error to disappear.

Hope this helps!