# Jquery in javascript not working for some reason

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make a menu that comes in from the left and then the body moves.
But for some reason my jQuery code won't work!

```html
<script src="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link src="jan.js"></link>
```

That's my html code. and my jQuery code in `js` is this:

```js
var menu = function() {
  $("div.menu_icon img").click(function() {
    $(".Menu").animate({
      left: 'opx'
    }, 200);

    $("body").animate({
      left: '285px'
    }, 200);
  });
}
$(document).ready(main);
```

Comment: `menu`, `main` -- is there a typo there somewhere?

Comment: Use `<script src="jan.js" type="text/javascript">`

Answer (score 0):

You don't include JS scripts using the `<link>` tag. Use `<script src="...">` instead:

```html
<!-- include jQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- include your script -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/your/javascript-file.js"></script>
```

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631635/can-i-load-javascript-code-using-link-tag) StackOverflow question.

Comment: And it's `type="text/javascript"`, not `src="text/javascript"` :)

Comment: Thanks. I edited it, but it's still not working though.

Comment: What is not working? Any error messages? Did you verify the browser tries to execute your JavaScript? Did you specify the correct file?

Comment: And I verified it multiple times, and checked the file. Really weird this

Comment: Does it work if you put the code inside the `<script>` tags and remove the `src` attribute?

Comment: I guess now you should do what others have suggested: replace your `main` with `menu`.

Answer (score 0):

Main should be menu?

```
 $(document).ready(menu);
```