# CSS and semantic ui cdn does not work in localhost

Tags: javascript, html, css, semantic-ui

My html structure is like below, and the folder path is correct:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Application</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="../app/assets/appStyle.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.6/semantic.min.css">
    <link rel="text/javascript" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.6/semantic.min.js">
</head>
```

When I try the pages from the browser, they work. However, when I try them from localhost, it does not load css or the minified semantic ui. Could anybody help please? I have been struggling with this for 3 hours. Any help or hint is appreciated.

EDITED: I have a function like below, for routing in my app.js file. Can it be a reason?

```
 // Make the user route to application.html
app.get('*',function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/public/pages/application.html'));
});
```

Comment: Are you getting errors in the console?

Comment: @abn No, I dont get any errors currently. I got a few times MIME type errors however, I don't get them now.

Comment: Did you see the browser asking for the resources? Is the server returning an http code?

Comment: Sometimes when I load the page, it gives"Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:2000/app/assets/appStyle.css" error

Comment: Pulling those resources works just fine for me. Are you sure the issue isn't with the local file `appStyle.css`?

Comment: I did not get your question, what kind of issue there can be?

Comment: try removing rel="stylesheet" from the tag and test.

Comment: it did not work

Answer (score 1):

I think problem is here

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="../app/assets/appStyle.css">
```

- If you want to check that stylesheet is working properly, right click
  the browser and click View page source.
- Click the stylesheet link and check is it load the stylesheet
  correctly.
- If it is not working properly check your path and correct that.

Comment: When I click on css file from the browser, it does not show the css file, loads the same page again with css file's path. How can I fix it?

Comment: It's a problem of your css path.Please drag your css file to same location of html file and give href="appStyle.css". I hope it will work

Comment: The problem is even if I give full path, it does not work

Comment: I think you have some mistake in your relative path.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `<link>` tag for Javascript. `<link>` tag is not supported by browsers to load JS. 
Please refer to this StackOverflow question: [Can I load javascript code using <link> tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631635/can-i-load-javascript-code-using-link-tag).

```
<link rel="text/javascript" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.6/semantic.min.js">
```

Use script tag to load JS.Try replacing above lines with:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.6/semantic.min.js"></script>
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: Add Jquery CDN just above the semantic.min.js CDN. Let me know if you are getting any other error.  Jquery CDN: <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

Comment: Please verify the supported version of Jquery for the version of Semantic-UI you are using. You can get Jquery CDN for different versions at: https://code.jquery.com/

Comment: I don't think so, I have used them before and it worked fine on localhost. Have you tried adding Jquery CDN?

Comment: Yes I added it, however it is still same problem

Comment: what is the error now? In previous comment, I added Jquery CDN, but formatting removed https:// from link, use authentic link from https://code.jqyery.com if it still showing jquery not found error. And have you defined /public as static source with some code similar to : app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));